# How to retrieve the port number from standard input for browser/server

Tags: java, sockets, browser, client-server

I'm reading Learning Java from O'Reilly, and am attempting to program the TinyHttpd class from the chapter on Network Programming. The problem I am running into is with extracting the port number from the Terminal. As a work around I created a default port number, but this too has failed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TinyHttpd {
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 1234;
    public static void main (String argv[] ) throws IOException {
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        if(argv.length>0){
                 ss = new ServerSocket( Integer.parseInt(argv[0]));
        }
        else{
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        }
        while(true)
            executor.execute( new TinyHttpdConnection( ss.accept( ) ) );
    }
}  

class TinyHttpdConnection implements Runnable {
    Socket client;
    TinyHttpdConnection ( Socket client ) throws SocketException {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run( ){
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream( ), "8859_1" )     );
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream( );
            PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter ( out, "8859_1"), true);
            String request = in.readLine( );
            System.out.println( "Request: " + request);
            Matcher get = Pattern.compile("GET /?(\\S*).*").matcher( request );
            if ( get.matches( ) ){
                request = get.group(1);
                if ( request.endsWith("/") || request.equals("") )
                    request = request + "index.html";
                try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( request     );
                    byte [] data = new byte [64*1024];
                    for(int read; (read = fis.read( data )) > -1;)
                        out.write( data, 0, read );
                    out.flush( );
                } catch ( FileNotFoundException e){
                    pout.println( "404 Object not found");
                }
            } else
                pout.println( "400 Bad Request" );
            client.close( );
        } catch ( IOException e) {
            System.out.println( "I/O error " +  e ); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean "failed". You got exception? Null or sth?

Comment: Clarify your problem. That code works fine and as expected for me.

Comment: When I run it in eclipse it compiles fine, but when it comes to runtime and I type in the hostname, port number, and filename it doesn't do anything. If I run it in terminal it won't even compile.

Comment: Give us the exact commands that you're trying to run.

Comment: http://localhost/Users/dwl3103/Desktop/W3SchoolsQuizTest.html

Comment: What does "If I run it in terminal it won't even compile" mean? You always have to a) compile and then b) run...

Comment: That url is to a resource on your local machine. It doesn't do us any good.

Comment: @home - sorry about the wording, but when I compile it in Terminal I get this error (error: Class names, 'TinyHttpd', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested). However I think I've got it working in eclipse now.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart http://raleigh.craigslist.org/app/2490201167.html

Comment: craigslist was the first thing I thought of when trying to find a suitable webpage to use as an example.

Comment: Okay, but I must be missing something because I don't see what you plan to do with a URL. I'm going to add an answer. See if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you posted in your question, I can do this sequence of steps in a bash shell:

1. Switch to projects directory
2. `mkdir tinyhttpd`
3. `cd tinyhttpd`
4. `vi TinyHttpd.java`
5. Copy your code in its entirety into the new file, `:x` to save and quit.
6. `javac TinyHttpd.java`
7. `java TinyHttpd 1235`

That starts your server on port 1235 instead of the default port of 1234. The default port works, too, if you don't specify a port. I verified it with `nc localhost 1235` followed by a `GET /<Enter>`, which got the expected "404 Object not found" since I don't have an index.html. Adding an index.html with content "hello world" makes it return that string, as expected.